Invalid tag unexpected tag "uuid" , Zabbix
I import template from .yaml file , bu get an error:  Invalid tag "/zabbix_export/groups/group(1)": unexpected tag "uuid".
https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/app/systemd?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F5.4
How i import this file in .xml format or is there another way??
Zabbix Version 5.4
